# Haw can i show the details of each with using many to many relationship using spring and thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to display the details of each user here is my class entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String nom ;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="user_user_detail",joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="id")},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="UserId")})
private Collection<UserDetail>userDetail ;
```

classe user detail

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userDetail")
public class UserDetail implements Serializable{
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long UserId;
private String adresse ;
```

My controller

```
  @RequestMapping(name="/vue", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String vue(Model model){

  User u=new User();
  List<User>p=new ArrayList<User>();

    p.add(u);
    p=ur.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("us",p);

    return "user" ;
    }
```

My view thymeleaf

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Nom</td>
<td>adresse</td>
</tr>

<tr th:each="t:${us}">
<td th:text="${t.Id}"></td>
<td th:text="${t.nom}"></td>
<td th:text="${t.getUserDetail()}"></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

i would to show the userdetail with

```
${t.getUserDetail()}">
```

but the result of details like this [org.sid.entity.UserDetail@1469f77e, org.sid.entity.UserDetail@78a81727]

please answer me quickly
thank's in advance

Comment: First, please note that "please answer me quickly" will generally not be met with kindness.  This is a site where you ask for help and responses may or may not be met with any urgency.

Comment: Second, your code is very confusing - please clean it up.  You are re-assigning `p`, so `p.add(u);` is probably meaningless.  You probably want `t.userDetail` instead of `t.getUserDetail()` and lower-case your `id` property.  Your result is printing the `toString()` method of your `UserDetail` class, so you'd need to override that if that's what you really want to print.